# Cloudflare + Forced SSL + auth on directory

Tags: htaccess, apache2, cloudflare

I hope I'm asking in the right area.

Here's what I have.  Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I have my main website in a vhost, call it domain.com.  This is proxied through CloudFlare.

I also have a vhost for manage.domain.com which listens on 80 and 443.  This is also proxied through CloudFlare and I have a .htaccess file in the root of the directory containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://manage.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The goal being that any visitors to this page get forced to HTTPS.
Under this vhost, I have a directory "audit".  This is gated by basic auth and also (attempting to) forced SSL.  This is the current version of my .htaccess file under /audit/:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authorized Access Only"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require user myuser
```

The current behavior is that manage.domain.com redirects to HTTPS as desired, but when I go to manage.domain.com/audit/, I'm prompted for auth **but in HTTP**, not HTTPS.  I want forced HTTPS for all things related to manage.domain.com.

I've spent the last ~2 hours Googling and all the answers out there (that reportedly work for other people) result in 1 of 3 results:

1. Too many redirects
2. Successful access to manage.domain.com/audit/ **without auth - EEK!**
3. Redirected back to my main website, domain.com

The only thing I can think of is that the CloudFlare proxy is involved and conflicting with my .htaccess redirects.  So is there a way to do what I want?  Simply force redirect to HTTPS *and then* prompt for auth.